# Periodically verify data stored correctly within Couchbase

Tags: couchbase

How can I run a check on couchbase to scrub / verify all the data in the database, and ensure it is free from errors ?

In MSSQL we have checkdb, on ZFS we have scrub - is there anything like this in couch ?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing because CouchDB is append-only DB and for this reason data corruption is not possible.

Comment: Data corruption is always possible.  The underlying storage may fault, to name just one of many scenarios.

Comment: In this case corruption is to be detected at the underlying level.

Answer (score -1):

You can use couchbase kafka adapter to stream data from couchbase to kafka and from kafka you can store in file system & validate as you like. [CouchbaseKafka](http://blog.couchbase.com/introducing-the-couchbase-kafka-connector) adapter uses TAP protocol to push data to kafka.

Another alternative to use existing [cbbackup](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/CLI/cbbackup_tool.html) utility to preform backup and data check as a side effect.